# How can access non-static method in static method (php)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I work on legacy code and I found this problem, in OrderService there is a static method `createOrder()` in which I want to check if the store is open or not

I want to make non-static method `openingHours()` to check in times.

Can I use ReflactionClass for this solution?

When I use `openingHours()` in `createOrder()` this error happens:

> Cannot use '$this' in non-object context.intelephense(1030)
> $this can not be used in static methods.php

`createOrder()` method:

```
 public static function createOrder(array $data {
// some logic 
 
     $is_opening = $this->openingHours();

     if ($is_opening != true) {

        $msg = trans('stores.not_available');
        $data['fail_msg'] = $msg;
        return $data;
     }
}
```

`openingHours()`

```
 public function openingHours($store){
      
    return 'hello';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Either createOrder can not be static or openingHours has to be static too.
Except if you have or create an instance in createOrder on which you can call the non static method openingHours like $store->openingHours().

Answer (score 0):

Consider to transform *createOrder()* in a non-static function.

If this is not feasible, the only way is to create an instance of the class in the static function:

```php
$is_opening = (new static)->openingHours();
```

or, if you need the dependency injection:

```php
$is_opening = app (__CLASS__)->openingHours();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me what is the meaning of `$store` variable? I guess it maybe holds the Store Model object, so I suggest to put `openingHours()` method in the Store Model Class.

```php
<?php
 
namespace App\Models;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 
class Store extends Model
{
    // ...
    public function isInOpeningHours(): bool // you can pass current timestamp or whatever you need to check this.
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Better than that I suggest to create a getter in your Store Model Class to get the opening hours in a form that is good to make a validation on it.

```php
<?php
 
namespace App\Models;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 
class Store extends Model
{
    // ...
    public function getOpeningHours(): array
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I don’t mean that

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to call a method that does not exist in the class and use `__callStatic` magic method to refer to the method needed.

```
Public function __callStatic($method, $args){
    if($method == "methodRefererToCreateOrderMethod"){
        $this->createOrder($args);
    }
}
```

And call it like this

```
Order::methodRefererToCreateOrderMethod($args)
```

I hope it works.

Comment: That can't work, the object must be instantiated somewehere

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new object inside the static function to access the non-static function,something like:

```
 public static function createOrder(array $data {
 // some logic 

 $is_opening = (new self)->openingHours();

 if ($is_opening != true) {

    $msg = trans('stores.not_available');
    $data['fail_msg'] = $msg;
    return $data;
 }
```

}

i hope this help you and if there is a problem, demonstrate more